# Visual Studio 2013- Post-build event - copy by main project bin folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, post-build-event

I want to copy dll files from projects in solution to the execute project folder by post-build.

Is there a way to get the startup project destination path as variable to post-build event of another projects in the solution?

Comment: Anyone? Please? I need to implement a solution with modules...

Answer (score 0):

Here all paths variables from msdn site.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42x5kfw4.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396